# R shiny subset based on user-input and then code based on the subset

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to use shiny server to do a calculation based on a subset - called sub1. 
sub1 works fine until I try to select certain column or try to run calculation on it.

sub1 is a subset from a large dataset.

Attached is my code. Let me know what i did wrong. Thank you so much.

```
server <- function(input,output) {
  data1 <- read.csv("..",fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

  sub1<- reactive(subset(data1,Sex == input$sex & AVS.Impairment == 
  input$impairment & Year == input$yr & Mortality <= max(input$mm) & Mortality 
  >= min(input$mm)))

  output$text<-renderDataTable(sub1())
  # I want to use the sub1 to run more calculation. 
  # But when I try to select the column and create column it won't work

   sub1$table = paste0(sub1$Sex) %>% tolower # this line doesn't work
   # error is object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: use sub1()$Sex  You are using a reactive function which is a closure.

Comment: Thanks Harlan. I tried it before. It didn't work.. Instead, it shows a different error ---  Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: By providing a reproducible example it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @MLavoie Thank you for your response. so it's a big dataset from the start. Then I get a subset based on the condition user input. But I want to run the calculation on the subset and generate a graph.

Comment: @MLavoie sub1 is generated. But I can't create new columns or select the column as the base-R function. I hope you know what I was trying to explain it. :) thanks

Comment: like I said we can't run your app without a reproducible example. You provided only haft of it. It can be several things that could explain your problem.

Comment: If you look at the R datasets package, you will find lots of data sets that can be used to recreate the problem you are experiencing.  That will let you generate are reproducible example.

Comment: Maybe sth along the lines of `output$text<-renderDataTable({ sub1 <- sub1() ; sub1$table = paste0(sub1$Sex) %>% tolower ; sub1 })`. But @HarlanNelson and @MLavoie are right: it'll be easier for you to get help if you make it reproducible (and added bonus: you might solve it along the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a reproducible example that can, if the indicated code us uncommented, produce the two errors you mention.  You will notice that the errors you are experiencing are very common with people when the first start using Shiny, so this answer is nothing new.

```
# Show two errors that occur in Shiny.  
# 1. The error that occurs when you try to use and input$var outside of a reactive context
# 2. The error that occurs when you treat a reative function as an dataset instead of a function.

library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
d <- datasets::longley
# Create a date field for dateRangeInput
d$date <- as.Date(as.character(d$Year),"%Y")
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Use of reactive in Shiny"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        dateRangeInput("yr", h3("Date range"),
                       start = min(d$date),  
                       end = '1962-05-01'),
        sliderInput("mm","Minimum GNP", 500,min=min(d$GNP),
                     max=max(d$GNP))
     ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         textOutput("text"),
         textOutput("text_err"),
         dataTableOutput("table")

      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  sub1 <- reactive({
    subset(d,GNP <=input$mm & Year >= year(input$yr[[1]]) & Year <= year(input$yr[[2]]))
  })

  # Uncomment this will produce   
  # Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
  # sub2 <-   subset(d,GNP <=input$mm & Year >= year(input$yr[[1]]) & Year <= year(input$yr[[2]]))

  output$text <- renderPrint(paste(year(input$yr[[1]]),year(input$yr[[2]])))

  # This will generate the error Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  # output$text_err <- renderPrint(paste(sub1$Year))

  output$table <- renderDataTable(sub1())

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for doing that Harlan!